# Why does the url not change upon redirection in php?

Tags: php, apache

I have a website based on PHP (with MySQL, Javascript, and JQuery)

Its URL remains unchanged even after the redirection to a new page. This happens for all redirections. If I open the link in a new tab, it will work fine and display the entire new URL but not on the same page. I do not get this issue on localhost, only on the server. What should I do to prevent that?

eg. mywebsite.com redirection to page1 should look like:
mywebsite.com/page1 but it doesn't change at all.

The redirection methods that I use is either:

```
header("Location: ../index.php?Login=error3");
```

or

```
 <a href="Forms/LogIn.php" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
```

Both redirection types do not change the URL.

Comment: please share minimal reproducible example. As per question it is not related to mysql.

Comment: The code for my website is very extensive. I don't know which snippet I should share because I don't know where the fault is.

Comment: share the redirection code you are using.

Comment: I have added that, thanks. I will be happy to provide more information if required

Comment: Please share your apache configuration

Comment: Sounds like you might not have a “real” domain, but just one of those framesets used to mask that content is actually loaded from a different address …?

Comment: What does your browser's devtools show?  Check the network tab, do you see the request, response, http code, etc?  Note [it is best to use fully qualified URLs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) for `header("Location: ....")` (see the "Note:").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain settings on the domain name website were wrong. Once I reset the settings to default, the full URL was visible again.